# How to stop form submit if validation fails in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Needing some help... I've researched solutions on stakeoverflow, but for some reason, my HTML form with validation, still submits, when it should not.

```
  <form class="submitForm" action="https://www.google.com" method="POST" id="form" target="_blank" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <span id="validationMessage" aria-live="polite"></span>
      <input class="nameInput" type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="urlInput" type="url" name="url" value="" id="url" placeholder="https://example.com">
      <button type="submit">go!</button>
  </form>
```

I've purposely removed **required** from the input fields, as I want to write my own validation.

But basically, the form should not submit, if the **text** input and **url** input fields have empty values.

But the form still submits!  What have I done wrong?

Here's my function to check if the URL is valid. Or if it's value is empty:

```
  function validateForm(data) {
    console.log('validate form');

    var url = data.url;
    var pattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;

    if (pattern.test(url)) {
        console.log("Url is valid");
        validationMessage.innerHTML = '';
        return true;
    } else if (url.length === 0 || url === '') {
        console.log("Url is not valid!");
        validationMessage.innerHTML = 'URL format is not correct. Please check your url';
        return false;
    }
  }
```

And here's my function, to check if the text value field is empty:

```
  function validateName(data) {
    // console.log('validate form');
    console.log('data.name', data.name.length);

    if (data.name.length > 1) {
      // validationMessage.innerHTML = 'Please input a bookmark name';
      console.log('there is a name!');
      return true;
    } else if (data.name === "" || data.name.length === 0) {
      // validationMessage.innerHTML = 'Please input a bookmark name';
      console.log('no name!');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

They both console log the correct scenarios, but the form still submits...

Updated: To answer posters question, **ValidateName()** gets called here:

```
  // ADD A NEW BOOKMARK
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      name: nameInput.value,
      url: urlInput.value
    };

    validateName(data);
    // validateForm(data);


    $.ajax({
      url: urlInput.value,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      statusCode: {
        200: function() {
          console.log( "status code 200 returned" );
          bookMarksArray.push(data);
          console.log("Added bookmark #" + data);
          localStorage.setItem("bookMarksArray", JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray));
          turnLoadingStateOn(bookMarksArray);
        },
        404: function() {
          console.log( "status code 404 returned. cannot add bookmark" );
        }
      }
   });
  });
```

Comment: Where does validateName get called?  All you've done is shown how it is declared.

Comment: @GeorgeJemptyHi George, have just updated the question to show where that gets called.  Have also provided a link... Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you need to return false from your submit handler if you don't want the form to submit

```
var namevalid = validateName(data);
!namevalid ? return false : null;
```